# Getting an element tree broken down from an XML

Tags: c#, xml, linq, visual-studio-2015

I have an XML and I am try to break down the elements so that it shows the path of every element. I have put an example of the code below and what the output I want to see.

The XML data is as per the below.

```
<a:Clients> 
    <a:Client1>
        <a:Initial>
          <a:FirstName>data</a:FirstName>
          <a:LastName>data</a:LastName>
        </a:Initial>
        <a:FirstName>data</a:FirstName>
        <a:MiddleName />
        <a:LastName>data</a:LastName>
        <a:Title>Mr</a:Title>
        <a:MaritalStatus>Divorced</a:MaritalStatus>
        <a:MaidenName>data</a:MaidenName>
```

I want to output it so it shows as

Clients/Client1

Clients/Client1/Initilal

Clients/Client1/Initial/FirstName

etc So I want to get all the elements of my xml to appear in this order for a large XML document. I dont want any data that sits inbetween the tags, Just the element paths.

I have written the below code in vs 2015 - Console Application to try and output it in this order but it is not working correctly. The c# code im using is:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.Xml.XPath;

namespace ConsoleApplication2
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XNamespace ns = "http://www.test.net/author/1.0";
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load("test.xml");
            var allElements  = doc.Descendants();
           foreach (var element in allElements)
           Console.WriteLine(allElements);
           Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

The output im currently getting is:

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kL7KH.jpg)

I have looked over Stack Overflow for answers but nothing seems to be exactly what I need and the ones I have tried have not worked either. Not sure if there is an easier way to do this?

Help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to do it in reversed order:

Client1/Clients

So i just entered all into a list and print it in reversed order later to be in the right order.

```
        XDocument doc = XDocument.Load("test.xml");
        var allElements = doc.Descendants();
        var elemants = doc.Elements();

        foreach (var element in allElements)
        {
            var current = element;
            List<string> names = new List<string>();
            while (current.Parent != null)
            {
                names.Add(current.Name.LocalName);
                current = current.Parent;
            }
            names.Add(current.Name.LocalName);
            names.Reverse();
            foreach(var name in names)
                Console.Write(name + "/");
            Console.WriteLine();
        }
```

I hope thats what you need.

Comment: Thanks mmm thats Brilliant. Im also trying to output it to a txt file but not having much luck. I tried FileStream filestream = new FileStream("out.txt", FileMode.Create);
var streamwriter = new StreamWriter(filestream);
streamwriter.AutoFlush = true;
Console.SetOut(streamwriter);
Console.SetError(streamwriter); but it doesnt seem to work. Any ideas?

Comment: Hi s.fry if this answer has solved your question please consider accepting it by clicking the check-mark.
and just use streamwriter.Write() instad of console.write();

Comment: Thanks mmm, really helpful and I have marked your response as the answer